# Migrating from Access to SSCE

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, ms-access

I have an application with databases in MS Access.  I want to migrate that to SSCE.
I have converted all the databases.  Problem is with datasets.

Do I need to make all new datasets or there is a way to convert the existing ones to SSCE datasets?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

They should remain unchanged except for the connection string to the database (datasets are based on ADO.NET which talks both Jet SQL and TSQL.

For instance if your datasets use table adapters for their data you can change the connection strings in the table adaptor properties using Visual Studio's dataset editor (just double click the xsd file, right click on the desired table adapter and choose properties; in the property pane you can set the connection appropriately).

Comment: Thanks a lot.  Could you advise how to initiate Visual Editor?